# eliminar elementos iguales de un array

Tags: java

En un `array` de enteros quiero eliminar los números que se repitan, como por ejemplo escogí el número **5**, y quiero eliminar todos los elementos del mismo que contengan ese valor.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class EliminarElementos {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        
     int []arr = {11,2,13,5,5,6,5,8};
        int []newArr = null;
        int elementoAeliminar = 5, conta = 0;
        
       
        for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        
        if(arr[i] == elementoAeliminar){
        
            conta++;
           }    
        }
        newArr = new int[arr.length-conta];
        
        
        for(int indiceArr = 0, indiceNewArr = 0; indiceNewArr < newArr.length; indiceArr++){
        
            if(arr[indiceArr] != elementoAeliminar){
            
                newArr[indiceNewArr] = arr[indiceArr];
                indiceNewArr++;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("el nuevo array es: "+ Arrays.toString(newArr));
}
}
```

**Resultado**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Resultado esperado**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Luis, ¿No es más fácil seleccionar el código en el editor, copiar y pegar? Poner imagénes no nos permite compilar el código o pegarlo en la respuesta para hacer más fácil explicar el error o la solución. Te recomiendo leer [ask] y completar el [tour] para entender qué es un [mcve]

Comment: ok, lo siento y muchas gracias por el consejo saludos.

Comment: Aunque ya te hayan respondido, recuerda que debes poner tu pregunta en forma de texto, pq la volviste a cambiar a imagen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu primera parte esta bien,en ella obtienes la cantidad de elementos repetidos para poder crear un nuevo arreglo

```java
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] == elementoAeliminar){
            conta++;
        }
    }
    newArr = new int[arr.length-conta];
```

Sin embargo en tu segundo for, lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente

```java
for(int indiceArr = 0, indiceNewArr = 0;  indiceNewArr < newArr.length; indiceArr++){
        if(arr[indiceArr] != elementoAeliminar){
            newArr[indiceNewArr] = arr[indiceArr];
            indiceNewArr++;
        }
    }
```

En este for lo que haces es declarar 2 variables, una para indexar el array inicial `arr` llamada  `indiceArr`, y otra para el arreglo nuevo `newArr` llamada  `indiceNewArr`, ambas inician en cero, este ciclo se repite mientras `indiceNewArr` sea menor a el tamaño de `newArr`

En el recorrido de este ciclo vas a tomar únicamente los elementos que sean diferentes del que quieres eliminar, eso lo logras con `if(arr[indiceArr] != elementoAeliminar)`, aquí asignaras a `newArr` los valores de `arr` usando las variables para indexar correspondientes a cada arreglo e incrementando la variable `indiceNewArr` cada vez que asignes un elemento a `newArr`

Comment: gracias mi amigo por ayudarme, gracias a ti aprendí más.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

ArrayList<int> myList = new ArrayList<int>();

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    if(arr[i] != elementoAeliminar)
    {
        myList.add(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Se crea un tipo de datos **ArrayList** que guardará los elementos diferentes al que se quiere eliminar, para ello se ejecuta un **ciclo for** que recorrerá todos los elementos del arreglo original preguntando si el número a eliminar es diferente al elemento del arreglo en curso, en caso de ser diferente se agrega a la **variable myList**.

Para recorrer los elemento guardados en la **variable myList** podemos hacer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) 
{
   System.out.println(myList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: gracias amigo te lo agradezco mucho.